# Making successful use of comparison operators with postgres oracle_fdw

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-fdw

I am trying to build a scripting system that maintains an ongoing relationship between an Oracle DB and a Postgres DB. On one particularly large table (50B rows), efficiency in the where clauses postgres-side is obviously crucial for syncing. However, I am finding my options in oracle_fdw to be pretty limited with regards to what stuff in the postgres WHERE clause actually transfers over to the Oracle side. In this case... comparison operators.

For example, on the postgres side when I execute this

```
explain
SELECT
    order_number
FROM
    orders 
WHERE
    order_number > '12345'
```

I get:

```
Foreign Scan on orders  (cost=10000.00..35675241480.00 rows=3567523148 width=9)
  Filter: ((order_number)::text > '12345'::text)
  Oracle
    query: SELECT /*0aacedb54006ca3542bcd999c312e859*/ r1."ORDER_NUMBER"
    FROM "ORDERS" r1 
(3 rows)
```

which shows that the comparison is not reaching Oracle and instead its going to attempt a full table download before doing the filtering locally. No bueno.

Ideally, I'd love for the BETWEEN condition to translate up.

```
SELECT
    order_number
FROM
    orders 
WHERE
    order_number between '12345' and '67890'
```

The only alternative I have been thinking of is making a foreign table with this query hard-coded. The only issue with that is the table will still return a huge number of rows and I won't have a way of fetching and incrementing batches at a time. My intention with the query is to only transfer about 10,000 at a time, since that is near the fdw prefetch limit. Its also the most I'd want to transfer between checkins to see what progress is.

If there were a way to make a foreign table as a remote query with variable fields, that would be handy?

Comment: Why are you comparing numbers with strings?

Comment: What version of Postgres and what version the `oracle_fdw` are you using?

Comment: What is the data type of `order_number` in PostgresSQL and Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The versions should have no impact on this, but of course it is always smart to include them in the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: If I remember correctly very old versions of the FDW did never push down any predicates - but of course you will know better ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I wish I could tell you why someone decided that numbers were best stored as strings. Not my decision. I got called in to fix things.

Comment: Postgres version is 10, FDW is 2.2.

Data type is string. There are indexes on the columns and the queries work "well" in Oracle...

Comment: Well, if `order_number` is indeed a varcahr, then `order_number > '12345'` is not going to do what you want, as `'2'` will be considered to be bigger than `'12345'`

Answer (score 0):

`oracle_fdw` does not push down inequality operators bezween string data types, because the result of such operations depends heavily on the string collation used.

There is no way to guarantee that the collation used on the Oracle side (which is written by Oracle) behaves identical to the collation in PostgreSQL. The query might well behave differently if the condition were pushed down, which would produce incorrect results.

If you compare numbers, use a numeric data type. Such comparisons will be pushed down.

Comment: Hmm, but if you send the string to be compared to the Oracle database as well, wouldn't that mean that only the Oracle collation will be used?

Comment: Right. But the result of a query must not change just because a condition is not pushed down. The behavior has to adhere to PostgreSQL semantics.

Comment: I would have expected differently and I think it would be acceptable (at least to me) if in such a case that there might be a discrepancy.

Comment: So I think your reasonings (on several accounts) are entirely fair. To clarify, the string comparison does work in this case because it is Oracle I am talking about (also because I tested it and it worked). The question is how to write a statement in Postgres so that it translates to the ultimately intended way in Oracle. And what @LaurenzAlbe is saying is that is just not possible because there isn't a consistent interpretation, which I understand.

Comment: However, it would be nice if there was an alternative, such as a way to write either direct-to-Oracle queries or perhaps an option flag that specifies your semantic preference. For example, if you set to Oracle, then no translation is done and if you set to postgres, then whatever translation can be made, is made (i.e. current, default).

Comment: You can use an Oracle query to define a foreign table: `... OPTIONS (table '(SELECT ...)')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If oracle_fdw did push down `<` for strings and the collation on the Oracle side behaves differently, the following could happen: if you add an `OR` clause to the query that is always `FALSE` but cannot be pushed down, the query result would change. At best I can imagine a FDW option `ignore_collation` with a big warning in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this to show what work-around I used to solve my problem.

It turns out that you can just create a foreign table "view" using the literal SQL method and update the SQL on the fly, like so:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE orders_and_items (
        ... (redacted)
)
SERVER "aasdsd" OPTIONS (table $s$(--QUERY DEFINED BY orders_and_items_range() FUNCTION--)$s$);
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE orders_and_items OPTIONS (ADD prefetch '10000', ADD readonly 'TRUE');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION orders_and_items_range(IN start_id INT, IN incr_amnt INT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    sql_exec TEXT;
BEGIN

incr_amnt := least(incr_amnt,1000000); -- this prevents unintended superlarge increments


-- This is the formal place where the query is defined for the orders_and_items table/view.
sql_exec := 
    $exec$
    ALTER FOREIGN TABLE orders_and_items OPTIONS (SET table $s$(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM orders o
    JOIN ordered_items oi USING (client,order_number,status)
    WHERE
        order_number BETWEEN '%1$s' AND '%2$s'
)$s$);
    $exec$
;

sql_exec := replace(sql_exec, chr(10), ' ');
sql_exec := replace(sql_exec, chr(9), ' ');

sql_exec := format(sql_exec, start_id, start_id + incr_amnt);

EXECUTE sql_exec;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
VOLATILE
;
```

This method allowed me to use forcibly pass the WHERE criteria through to Oracle. Usage is like so:

```
select orders_and_items_range(67160673, 100000);

select * from from orders_and_items;
```

which would produce the equivalent of:

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM orders o
    JOIN ordered_items oi USING (client,order_number,status)
    WHERE
        order_number BETWEEN '67160673' AND '67260673'
```

as if it were executed exclusively on the Oracle side, which I would not be able to do otherwise.

Regrettably very hacky - but works very reliably and is 99.9% as fast and the only way I could get around my obstacles.